# How can I go throught every tab in Excel file to evaluate header value in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I've a SSIS solution to import data from Excel file to SQl Server table.
But the Excel file have differents tabs and I need to go for each one evaluating the header value for A1 cell, if it's for sample "Appointment Count", that is the tab I have to imported.

some idea how can I do it?

thanks 
Eliana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an OLEDB connection manager, using the Microsoft Jet Provider to open the Excel file.  From there, you can create a For Each loop container to iterate through the worksheets therein.

For an example of [how to implement this, check here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/395541/How-to-load-data-from-multiple-Excel-sheets-to-any).

*Remember that the MS Jet provider is available in 32-bit only.